# Why does TokenStorage behave incorrectly between Behat scenarios?

Tags: symfony, oauth, behat, symfony-2.6, symfony-security

In our Symfony applications we have custom code that handles authentication. It's based on top of [thephpleague/oauth2-server](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server).

We have 2 types of authentication, both of which end up calling `TokenStorage::setToken()`.

All this works perfectly.

Now we decided to add some Behat tests to our bundle:

```
Scenario: I am able to login with type 1
    When I login with type 1
    Then I am successfully logged in as a "type1" member

Scenario: I am able to login with type 2
    When I login with type 2
    Then I am successfully logged in as a "type2" member
```

(I changed the actual wording of the scenarios in order not to expose business-specific terms)

In order to test the `Then` steps, I need access to the `TokenStorage` in my Contexts because I basically want to test if the user has the correct security role:

```
default:
    gherkin:
        cache: null
    suites:
        mybundle:
            paths: [ %paths.base%/src/My/Bundle/Features ]
            contexts:
                - My\Bundle\Context\LoginContext
                    tokenStorage: '@security.token_storage'
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension:
            kernel:
                env: "test"
                debug: "true"
```

My context looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;

class LoginContext implements Context
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @Then I am successfully logged in as a :expectedRole member
     */
    public function iAmSuccessfullyLoggedInAsAMember($expectedRole)
    {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getRoles() as $role) {
            if ($role->getRole() == $expectedRole) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (! $found) {
            throw new \Exception('Incorrect role');
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is:

- if I run **only the first** scenario, it works OK
- if I run **only the second** scenario, it works OK
- if I run both of them, then **on the 2nd scenario** I get the error `Call to a member function getRoles() on a non-object`

Why does this happen ? How can I make it work correctly ?

My versions are:

- **behat/behat**: 3.1.0
- **behat/gherkin**: 4.4.1
- **behat/symfony2-extension**: 2.1.1
- **symfony/symfony**: 2.6.13

---

One solution I tried is to have my context implement the `Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelAwareContext` interface instead and then I did this:

```
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelAwareContext;
use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\BeforeScenarioScope;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

class LoginContext implements KernelAwareContext
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $kernel;

    public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     */
    public function getDependencies(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
    {
        $container = $this->kernel->getContainer();

        $this->tokenStorage = $container->get('security.token_storage');
    }
}
```

My thinking was that, by explicitly retrieving `TokenStorage` **before** each scenario, I would get a fresh instance each time and therefore it would work.

However, it behaved exactly the same :( .

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried executing while using @insulated tag for your feature or scenarios? this should give you a fresh instance for each scenario.

Comment: @lauda This is the first time I'm hearing about that annotation. I'll look into it and give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: So apparently this problem appears because the `TokenStorage` instance that is used inside my bundle is different from the one that I get in my `Context`. I don't know yet why this happens, but I suspect it's because they come from 2 different instances of the DI container. Will keep investigating.